# Function as an eigenvector for a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So I am currently going through this paper: [Link Here](http://users.ictp.it/~pub_off/lectures/lns017/Kenyon/Kenyon.pdf)

And in section 2.2, it defines $K$ to be a weighted adjacency matrix for a certain rectangular $n$ by $m$ graph, where the weights are all either $1$ or $i$. It then goes on to say that for fixed $j$ and $k$, the function:

$$ f(x,y)=\sin\frac{\pi j x}{m+1}\sin\frac{\pi k y}{n+1}$$

is an eigenvector of $K$. My question is, what does this mean? $K$ is a matrix with strictly $\mathbb{C}$ valued entries, so my understanding is that it can only act on vectors in $\mathbb{C}^n$ for some $n$. What does it mean for this matrix to act on a function?

For example, when $m=2$ and $n=3$, we have the matrix:
$$ K = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & i & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & i & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & i \\
    i & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & i & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & i & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

In this case, what are the eigenvectors that it is referring to?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the standard basis of the vector space the linear operator $K$ acts on is most easily enumerated by two indexes $x,y$ where $x\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$ and $y\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$. To specify a vector in this space, we need to specify the component this vector has for each possible combination of $x$ and $y$ from these sets. That is, to specify a vector, we may specify a function $f\colon\{1,\ldots,m\}\times\{1,\ldots,n\}\to\Bbb C$. And that is precisely what happens here.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand, what is the vector space in question here?

Comment: @ASKASK It is $\Bbb C^{n\cdot m}$. An $nm$-tuple of complex numbers is nothing but a map from a fixed index set of size $nm$ to $\Bbb C$. For convenience (because it fits nicely with the underlying graph incidences encoded in $K$), the index set is picked to be $\{1,\ldots,m\}\times\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

Comment: Sorry I am still having trouble wrapping my head around this, can you give me an example of such a vector in the space and what its components would be?

Comment: Okay I understand that, but I still do not see how in this paper that function is "easily" seen to be an eigenvector. Can you help me with that?

Comment: A simpler example. A vector in $\Bbb C^5$ is a 5-tuple $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)$ of complex values, for example $(1,4,9,16,25)\in \Bbb C^5$. In stead of listing the bvalues, we can choose any description we like to associate a  value in $\Bbb C$ with each of the indices $\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. For example, the vector above is given by the function $f\colon\{1,2,3,4,5\}\to \Bbb C$, $k\mapsto k^2$.

Comment: "Since $G$ is a 'product' of two line graphs, the eigenvectors are the product of the eigenvectors of the line graphs individually."

Comment: Sorry I'm unfamiliar with what the "product" of a graph is

Comment: It is also not clear to me how in this case we are expected to convert an index set $x,y\in \{1...m\}\times\{1...n\}$ to a single integer in the range $\{1...mn\}$. It can easily be done but I do not see what convention is being used here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38208/discussion-between-hagen-von-eitzen-and-askask).

Comment: I have added more details to my question